# Why does my js function only find the first image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loading

I am writing a function that uses pxLoader to load images in a set of thumbs. When they are loaded it hides the loader and fades the image in. Here is the markup:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:1px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb front">
    <div class="rsTmb portfolio">
          <img class="the-image" src="<!-- image loaded from cms -->">
        <div class="image-loader"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then here is my js function for it:

```
loadThumbs: function () {
    var app = this;

    $('.rsThumb').each( function () {

        var $mainHolder = $(this).find('.rsTmb');

        var $mainImage = $mainHolder.find('img');
        console.log($mainImage);

        $mainImage.addClass('the-image');
        $mainImage.parent().append('<div class="image-loader"></div>');

        var $mainImageSrc = $mainImage.attr('src');

     //                                                   //
    // Load the thumbs                                   //
   // ------------------------------------------------- //

          var pxLoader  = new PxLoader();

          var pxImage   = pxLoader.addImage($mainImageSrc);

          pxLoader.addCompletionListener(function () {

            $('.image-loader').hide();

            $('.the-image', $mainHolder) 
              .attr('src', $mainImageSrc) // Update the image source
              .transition({ // Fade the image in
                opacity: 1
            }, 300); 

          });

          pxLoader.start();

      });

}
```

For some reason when iterating over the images to replace the image when its finished it finds the first one and loads that into all of the divs. In my console I get all the images etc but no joy with the urls being different, they are all the same as the first one.

It might be me thats being stupid but I have tried allsorts of things.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions about your code:

- Firstly, there is something i don't understand: you are retrieving your image src attribute (`var $mainImageSrc = $mainImage.attr('src');`) then in the completion listener your are replacing its value with the same one `$('.the-image', $mainHolder).attr('src', $mainImageSrc)`. Is there a reason ?
- Another thing is about this instruction `.transition({ opacity: 1 }, 300);`. Is it a pxLoader function or are you using another jquery plugin to do this, cause i am not aware about a `transition()` function in jQuery. You can use the `fadeIn()` function available in jQuery.

Please tell me if i misunterstood, but you want to show something like loading spinners while images are loading (from your cms) like in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtYas/) (clear your browser cache if you run it multiple times), no ?
This code seems to work so could you give us more context ? How/When are you calling your `loadThumbs()` function ? Do you have a test-case url or could you set up a jsFiddle ?

Comment: Hi Yeah, I am using pxLoader and above this code there is another variable that basically stores the mainImage img src attribute and then replaces it once pxLoader has said that the image is now downloaded. Sorry, in the end this script actually worked :)